# Prove/disprove the matrix convergence in probability

Tags: probability, matrices, convergence-divergence

**Problem:**

Given $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $N\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $D\in \{N, N+1, N+2, \cdots\}$, a random matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is generated by the following steps:

$(1)$ Randomly select $N$ numbers from $\{1,2,\cdots,D\}$ to form a sequence $p=\{p_i\}_{i=1}^N$.

$(2)$ Then calculate $\mathbf{A}=[a_{ij}]_{N\times N}$, where $a_{ij}=e^{-\alpha |p_i - p_j|}$.

Please prove or disprove the following proposition:

> $\mathbf{A}$ converges to $\mathbf{I}_N$ in probability, *i.e.*, for any $\epsilon>0$ and choice of norm $\|\cdot\|$, there is:
> $$
> \mathbb{P}[\|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}_N\|\geq\epsilon]\to0~~(D\rightarrow \infty).
> $$

---

**My Efforts:**

I am confused by how to start.

I may know that the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{A}$ will be all ones, since $|p_i-p_i|=0$.

And I may know that all elements of $\mathbf{A}$ are in $[0,1]$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric.

Intuitively, I guess that when $D$ increases, the absolute distances between each two $p_i$s may become larger and larger, so $a_{ij}$ is expected to be smaller and smaller.

I also write the following Python program for numerical validation:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy import spatial

alpha = 1
N = 10
I = np.eye(N)
for D in range(N, 10000):
    MSE = 0.0
    for i in range(100):
        p = np.array(random.sample(range(1, D + 1), N)).reshape(N, 1)
        A = np.exp(-alpha * spatial.distance.cdist(p, p))
        MSE += np.sum((A - I) ** 2.0)
    MSE /= (100 * N * N)
    print(MSE)
```

I can see that when $D$ increases, the mean squared error between $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{I}_N$ converges to zero.

```
0.027683220252563596
0.02508590350202309
0.02317795057344325
...
0.0001934704436327538
0.00032059290537374806
0.0003270223508894337
...
5.786435956425624e-05
1.1065792791574203e-05
5.786469182583059e-05
```

How to prove/disprove the proposition by exactly analysing the process of $D\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (original, now edited out of the question) claim that $A=I_N$ whp is false.

For any $j\neq k$, the $(j,k)$<sup>th</sup> entry of $I_N$ is $0$.  But the $(j,k)$<sup>th</sup> entry of $A$ is $e^{-\alpha|p_j-p_k|}$.  Thus \begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[{A=I_N}]&\leq\mathbb{P}[{0=e^{-\alpha|p_j-p_k|}}] \\
&=\mathbb{P}[{\infty=\alpha|p_j-p_k|}] \\
&=0
\end{align*} since $\alpha$ is a constant and $|p_j-p_k|$ is a.s. finite.

With that said, $A$ converges to $I_N$ in probability: for any $\epsilon$ and choice of norm $\|\cdot\|$, the value $$\mathbb{P}[\|A-I_N\|\geq\epsilon]\to0$$

To see this, note that all norms are equivalent on the finite-dimensional vector space of $N\times N$ matrices; I will choose the $\infty\to1$ norm $$\|M\|=\sum_{j,k}{|M_{j,k}|}$$

Then \begin{align*}
\|A-I_N\|&=\sum_{j,k}{|(A-I_N)_{j,k}|} \\
&=\sum_{j<k}{2e^{-\alpha|p_j-p_k|}} \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Now, pick your favorite function $f(D)$ that is $\omega(1)$ (i.e., grows without bound) but $o(D)$ (for example, $f(D)=\sqrt{D}$).  Since $p_j$ and $p_k$ are (assumed) pairwise independent, $$\mathbb{P}[{|p_j-p_k|\leq f(D)}]\leq\frac{f(D)}{D}\to0$$  Taking the complement, $$2e^{-\alpha|p_j-p_k|}\leq2e^{-\alpha f(D)}\to0$$ on an event of probability arbitrarily close to $1$.

The value (1) is the sum of $\binom{N}{2}$-many such terms; the latter is finite and independent of $D$, so if each term converges to $0$ whp, the sum must converge to $0$ as well.

Comment: Hi @JacobManaker, thanks for your help! I think my previous statement of the proposition is not true. The true one should be with $\mathbb{P}[\|A-I_N\|\geq\epsilon]\to0$ as you mentioned. And I also do not know how to prove or disprove $\mathbb{P}[\|A-I_N\|\geq\epsilon]\to0$. Could you please provide some ideas about that?

Comment: Hi @JacobManaker, I have edited the problem to make the statements accurate.

Comment: @BinChen: In general, it's considered bad form here to edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers (but no harm, no foul in this case).  I've updated my answer to include more details for the problem you actually meant.

Comment: Hi @JacobManaker, thanks for your kind reminder! I understand what your mean. I will pay more attention about this. Such bad problem editing will not occur in the future.

Comment: Hi @JacobManaker, thanks for providing more details! I can partially understand your answer now. I think that your introduction of $f(D)$ is a quite key and amazing step. In addition, I may have three problems as follows:

Comment: $(1)$ "To see this, note that all norms are equivalent on the finite-dimensional vector space of $N\times N$ matrices;". I may understand that the main body of your analysis is based on a special case. But I do not understand why "all norms are equivalent".

Comment: $(2)$ I have not touched the concept of "$\infty \rightarrow 1$ norm". I guess this is a norm similar to $\ell_1$-norm of a vector. I also know the Frobenious norm of a matrix. I may not find this concept from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm. Did I miss something?

Comment: For $(1)$: I notice that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm introduces the concept of "Equivalence of norms" at the buttom of its webpage.

Comment: $(3)$ Can the original proposition be written as: $\left(\forall \epsilon >0,~\underset{D\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}\left[ \lVert \mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}_N \rVert \ge \epsilon \right] =0\right)$? Can I deduce the following proposition from it? $\underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}{\lim}\left(\underset{D\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}\left[ \lVert \mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}_N \rVert \ge \epsilon \right] \right)=\underset{D\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \left( \underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}{\lim}\mathbb{P}\left[ \lVert \mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}_N \rVert \ge \epsilon \right] \right) = 0$

Comment: @BinChen: Following links, Wikipedia eventually cites [this article by Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/equivnorms.pdf), which explains quite well (IMHO) why all the norms are equivalent.  The equation immediately following "$\infty\to1$ norm" is the definition thereof; it is the operator norm with the inputs measured in $\ell^{\infty}$ but the outputs in $\ell^1$.

Comment: Wrt (3): Yes, the proposition I prove is your first equation, $(\forall\epsilon>0\text{, ...})$.  The interchange of limits you ask for is false; since probability measures are continuous, taking the limit in $\epsilon$ first gives $\mathbb{P}[{\|A-I_N\|=0}]$, which we know has probability $0$ for any $D$.

Comment: I accept this answer. I am particularly grateful to @JacobManaker for his/her efforts and kind help with such a long answer and detailed explanations.

Comment: Hi @JacobManaker, if $\mathbf{A}$ converges to $\mathbf{I}_N$ in probability. Can I prove/disprove that $\mathbb{E}[\ln(\det(\mathbf{A}))]$ converges to $0$? I try to learn something from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008712/convergence-of-the-expectation-of-a-bounded-random-variable, but this problem is too complicated for me. I can not handle it now. How can I do?

Comment: Hi @JacobManaker, I am sorry to disturb you again. I post this problem at another place: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529767/prove-disprove-mathbbe-ln-det-mathbfa-rightarrow-0-when-bounded.